# scroll bar did not display in adminLTE template

Tags: javascript, html, css, adminlte

I am using adminLTE template with fixed sidebar. i have issue in the sidebar section. when i click sub menu, sidebar scroll not displayed. but when i load chrome inspect element section, scrollbar appeared. why is that? please check attached images

[image: scroll bar not appear]

but when i load inspect element, scroll bar appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also facing same issue.The problem from scroll plugin height detection .For first time load its read some height and add scroll on respected data.

Then you expand the menu .its still perform the same height.

> **Why its working after developer mode open ?**
>
> Because the window was resized that scroll plugin detect new height

So we need manualy trigger the resize event on expand menu click/hover .use below code on click/hove while expand menu

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  },10)
```

create click/hover event on menu `(inspect to find classname)`

```
$(document).on('click hover','classnameOfMenu',function(){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  },10)
})
```

Comment: prasanth, its working, but i have a problem. need to wait till scroll :(

Comment: yes do it . While menu expand, its have some animation time delay .That why we use setTimeout

Comment: i reduced and check it. but nothing happen. still same timing

Comment: increase the time delay above `1000`